# RadioButtonList not allign with the Label, CSS issue

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a `radioButtonList` for which I have the label in `ASP`, the `radioButtonList`  displaying correctly but it is not align with the label created for it.

**What I exactly need is to**

**1- Align the `radioButtonList` with the label**

**2- Label of radio buttons must be close to radio buttons.**

as shown below image;

[image]

My ASP code:

```
 <div style="display: inline;" dir="rtl">
                   <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="Server" Text=" Permenat office"></asp:Label> 
                <asp:Label ID="Label35" runat="Server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>


                <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rdlstPermenantOffice" >
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>


                </div>
```

Comment: You know that by default, the text on the radio button goes on the right, right?

Comment: Works for me. There must be some CSS you're not showing that affects this.

Comment: @LcSalazar So what if the OP chooses to have the buttons to the right? That has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry @Mr Lister, but the OP enumerated 2 items that he wanted solved. But he provided an image to what he was trying to achieve, and simply solving the align issue (following the 2 steps established) wouldn't give him the exactly result he showed on the image. My intention was to aggregate, not to criticize.

Comment: @LcSalazar Hm, now you explain it like that... the OP's text can be interpreted that way, yes. I took the picture as a screenshot of what he has now, and the red arrows as where the black labels should go to (i.e. closer to the radio buttons). But I could be wrong. Let's hear what the OP has to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it works fine:-

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblChoose" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
 RepeatLayout="Flow">
   <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```